# Tastypie: I want to get items like "/places/{PLACE_ID}/comments" but how?

Tags: django, tastypie

Let's say I want to get comments about a place. I want to make this request:

**/places/{PLACE_ID}/comments**

How can I do this with TastyPie?

Comment: is place_id the primary key for places?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Follow the example in [Tastypie's docs](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#nested-resources) and add something like this to your `places` resource:

```
class PlacesResource(ModelResource):

    # ...

    def prepend_urls(self):
        return [
            url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<pk>\w[\w/-]*)/comments%s$" % (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()), self.wrap_view('get_comments'), name="api_get_comments"),
    ]

    def get_comments(self, request, **kwargs):
        try:
            obj = self.cached_obj_get(request=request, **self.remove_api_resource_names(kwargs))
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return HttpGone()
        except MultipleObjectsReturned:
            return HttpMultipleChoices("More than one resource is found at this URI.")

        # get comments from the instance of Place 
        comments = obj.comments # the name of the field in "Place" model

        # prepare the HttpResponse based on comments
        return self.create_response(request, comments)           
     # ...
```

The idea is that you define a url mapping between the `/places/{PLACE_ID}/comments` URL and a method of your resource (`get_comments()` in this example). The method should return an instance of `HttpResponse` but you can use methods offered by Tastypie to do all the processing (wrapped by `create_response()`). I suggest you take a look at `tastypie.resources` module and see how Tastypie processes requests, in particular lists.