# Django Tastypie prepend_urls error

Tags: python, django, api, tastypie

Django-tastypie error. I am trying to prepend_urls so that I can list friends for a user but I get  an error **" NameError at /api/v1/friends/user/1/  global name 'url' is not defined"**.
Here is the code for the Friends Resource.

```
class FriendsResource(ModelResource):
      from_user=fields.ForeignKey(UserResource,'from_user')
      to_user=fields.ForeignKey(UserResource,'to_user')


      class Meta:
           queryset=Friends.objects.all()
           serializer=Serializer(formats=['json'])
           resource_name='friends'
           filtering={
                       'from_user':ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
                       'to_user':ALL_WITH_RELATIONS

           }
```

and here is the code for prepend_urls and the method to put into wrap_view.

```
def get_users(self,request):
       self.method_check(request,['get'])
       friends = []
       for friend in Friends.objects.filter(Q(from_user=request.user)|Q(to_user=request.user)):
            friends.append(friend)      

  def prepend_urls(self):
       return [

             url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<pk>\w[\w/-]*)/user%s$" %(self._meta.resource_name,trailing_slash()),
                   self.wrap_view('get_users'),name= 'api_get_friends_for_user')
               ]
```

Here is the Traceback:

```
  Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/api/v1/friends/user/1/

Django Version: 1.6.2
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'tastypie',
 'userprof',
 'relations',
 'event',
 'liking',
 'feed')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/root/python/django-zack/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  101.                 resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
File "/root/python/django-zack/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  318.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/root/python/django-zack/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  346.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/root/python/django-zack/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  341.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/root/python/django-zack/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.2-py2.7.egg/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  40.         __import__(name)
File "/root/python/django-zack/wyat/wyat/urls.py" in <module>
  25.      url(r'^api/',include(v1_api.urls)),
File "/root/python/django-zack/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/api.py" in urls
  107.             pattern_list.append((r"^(?P<api_name>%s)/" % self.api_name, include(self._registry[name].urls)))
File "/root/python/django-zack/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py" in urls
  324.         urls = self.prepend_urls()
File "/root/python/django-zack/wyat/event/api.py" in prepend_urls
  68.                  url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<pk>\w[\w/-]*)/user%s$" %(self._meta.resource_name,trailing_slash()),

Exception Type: NameError at /api/v1/friends/user/1/
Exception Value: global name 'url' is not defined
```

Please tell me where I am wrong because I used the example from the cookbook on nested resources and I can't see where I'm wrong.

Comment: Can you check if you have imported from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve. Let me know if this is the case

Comment: @Sumuga Even after importing it I still get the same error. Could my syntax be wrong or maybe it's the django version I'm using 1.6.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Zacmwa

I have a working prepend_urls .. you can take a look at the following example.

```
def prepend_urls(self):
        return [
            url(r"^(?P%s)/generate%s$" %
                (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()),
                self.wrap_view('genusr'), name="api_get_genusr"),
        ]

def genusr(self, request, **kwargs):
        data = self.deserialize(request, request.body, format=request.META.get('Content-Type', 'application/json'))
        print(data.get('workflows',None))
        child_resource = UserResource()
        return child_resource.get_list(request)
```

And the above methods is wrappered inside my resource model.

Error is likely to be caused due to some missing imports kindly try to import **django.core.urlresolvers import resolve, from tastypie.utils import trailing_slash** and try again. Let me know what happens when you do this.

Comment: Thanks. I needed to import django.conf.url. Now my only problem is the syntax for the url. I want it to show api/v1/friends/user/1 where 1 is the id of the user but I  get an error message **Invalid resource lookup data provided.** How should my url be written.

Comment: I am using prepend_urls for nested resources so I can list a user's friends as per the first suggestion in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19707400/how-to-do-automatic-filtering-based-on-the-current-user-with-tastypie. Could you kindly show me how to do this. And also can i pass a friends array as per my get_users method.`def get_users(self,request):
       self.method_check(request,['get'])
       friends = []
       for friend in Friends,objects.filter(Q(from_user=request.user)|Q(to_user=request.user)):
            friends.append(friend)`

Comment: There is a method to do this. You have mention that the user/ will be followed by a primary key in the regex that you have written in the prepend_urls method. Take a look at the following post. It has the primary key as you mentioned above http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877437/tastypie-i-want-to-get-items-like-places-place-id-comments-but-how